# Android Samck message timeout

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Hello everyone,
             I am working on a chat application using a smack lib ( Samck4.0.3 ). Since smack have ability to send off line message. I want to know what is timeout of this message. I send a message to user2 and he is off line. I want to know after how many days this message is neglected by smack. If user2 became on line after 20 days or a month. Does he receive that message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi if you're using OpenFire you can configure that from your Admin Panel, but normally all the offline messages will remain till the user get connected even after 20 days

EDIT

Here we go from here

[image]

Comment: Thank you nadir. But can you tell me the exact name of that property?